# Jenkins build failing to install pngquant

Tags: docker, jenkins, webpack, build

I'm running this [Jenkins Image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/) in Docker.

In one of my builds, I'm attempting to install the following packages:
`json
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.8.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "webpack": "^4.0.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1"
  }`

However, the build keeps failing when attempting to install `pngquant-bin@4.0.0`:

```
> node-sass@4.8.3 install /var/jenkins_home/workspace/crypto-coaster/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.8.3/linux-x64-57_binding.node
Download complete
Binary saved to /var/jenkins_home/workspace/crypto-coaster/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57/binding.node
Caching binary to /var/jenkins_home/.npm/node-sass/4.8.3/linux-x64-57_binding.node

> cwebp-bin@4.0.0 postinstall /var/jenkins_home/workspace/crypto-coaster/node_modules/cwebp-bin
> node lib/install.js

  ✔ cwebp pre-build test passed successfully

> gifsicle@3.0.4 postinstall /var/jenkins_home/workspace/crypto-coaster/node_modules/gifsicle
> node lib/install.js

  ✔ gifsicle pre-build test passed successfully

> mozjpeg@5.0.0 postinstall /var/jenkins_home/workspace/crypto-coaster/node_modules/mozjpeg
> node lib/install.js

  ✔ mozjpeg pre-build test passed successfully

> optipng-bin@3.1.4 postinstall /var/jenkins_home/workspace/crypto-coaster/node_modules/optipng-bin
> node lib/install.js

  ✔ optipng pre-build test passed successfully

> pngquant-bin@4.0.0 postinstall /var/jenkins_home/workspace/crypto-coaster/node_modules/pngquant-bin
> node lib/install.js

  ⚠ The `/var/jenkins_home/workspace/crypto-coaster/node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant` binary doesn't seem to work correctly
  ⚠ pngquant pre-build test failed
  ℹ compiling from source
  ✔ pngquant pre-build test passed successfully
  ✖ Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed
    at Promise.all.then.arr (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/crypto-coaster/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/execa/index.js:231:11)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

I've updated the Docker image, tried different versions of Node (7.9.0, 8.11.1) and keep running into the same error.

No idea how to fix get `pngquant-bin` working on this build.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see the following error in the output: `Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this issue https://github.com/imagemin/pngquant-bin/issues/78.
I use this dockerfile to create a new image and it work fine.

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc make libpng-dev
USER jenkins
```